# Accessed denied when attempting to permission folder using the Object Model API

Tags: object-model, permissions

I'm attempting to permission a folder using the Object Model API that is created by an ASP.NET page wrapped into a feature. I am able to create and permission the folder for users that are in the appropriate SharePoint role however, I need to permission the folders that are also in more restrictive roles. The folders are created with no problem but I need to break the inheritance and permission the folder.

I attempted to wrap the folder creation/permission code in

```
SPSecurity.RunWithElevatedPrivileges(delegate() { ... });
```

I also tried using

```
web.AllowUnsafeUpdates = true;
```

and

```
web.Site.WebApplication.FormDigestSettings.Enabled = false;
...
web.Site.WebApplication.FormDigestSettings.Enabled = true;
```

The folder is always created however it does not permission properly. Any feedback/direction would be appreciated. Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Have you tried [impersonating a user](http://blackninjasoftware.com/2009/04/09/how-to-programmatically-impersonate-users-in-sharepoint/) with the necessary rights:

Comment: I just tried impersonating a user with the necessary rights and the folder is created as the impersonated user however it does not permission and I am getting the error: "The security validation for this page is invalid. Click Back in your Web browser, refresh the page, and try your operation again." Any ideas on how to overcome this? Thanks.

Comment: Thanks for your help, I posted an answer of how I got it to work. I used a combination of your answer and another resource online.

Answer (score 0):

Did you get a new instance of SPWeb inside the RunWithElevatedPrivileges delegate? If not, it will use the same credentials as the original request.

Answer (score 0):

I ended up getting it to work with a combination of Koen Vosters [answer](https://sharepoint.stackexchange.com/questions/2702/accessed-denied-when-attempting-to-permission-folder-using-the-object-model-api/2707#2707) and [this link](http://www.wictorwilen.se/Post/BreakRoleInheritance-and-AllowUnsafeUpdates.aspx).

After impersonating the user I had to use:

```
web.AllowUnsafeUpdats = true;
...
list.BreakRoleinheritance(true);
web.AllowUnsafeUpdates = true;
while (list.RoleAssignments.Count > 0)
{
   list.RoleAssignments.Remove(0);
}
...
//Add necessary permissions
```